# Highlight text temporarily

Tags: javascript, highlight

I'm trying to create an internal link to scroll to bottom highlight a tag. When I try the code above it doesn't highlight, I have to refresh the page to make it work.

```html
<p>Fındık eski Çin yazmalarında anlaşıldığına göre yaklaşık 5.000
    yıllık bir geçmişi olan Avrupa'nın mistik
    <sup><a href="#mistisizm">[1]</a></sup> ve orta çağlardan, Romalılardan...

<script>
function highlight(elemId){
  var elem = $(elemId);
  elem.css("backgroundColor", "#ffffff"); // hack for Safari
  elem.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffaa' }, 1500);
  setTimeout(function(){$(elemId).animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 3000)},1000);
}

if (document.location.hash) {
  highlight(document.location.hash);
}
$('a[href*=#]').click(function() {
  var elemId = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
  highlight(elemId);
});
</script>
```

How can I make this snippet work without reloading the page?

Comment: Does the click fire correctly? Cause I tested the `highlight()` and it works fine. Maybe you can share some html as well

Comment: When I click the link it jumps to id but highlighting doesn't fire.

Comment: so the problem isn't in the `highlight()` method, but in your `a.click()` - need html to confirm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have multiple issues here.
Your css selector attribute name needs to be in quotes. Without it the code gives

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: a[href*=#"]

Second, when you select an element with JQuery, it returns list of elements, but `animate` has to be called implicitly for single elements, so fixed code looks like this:

```
<script>
    function highlight(elemId){
        let elem = $(elemId);
        elem.css("backgroundColor", "#ffffff"); // hack for Safari
        elem[0]?.animate({ backgroundColor: '#ffffaa' }, 1500);
        setTimeout(function(){elem[0]?.animate({ backgroundColor: "#ffffff" }, 3000)},1000);
    }

    if (document.location.hash) {
        highlight(document.location.hash);
    }
    $('a[href*="#"]').click(function() {
        let elemId = '#' + $(this).attr('href').split('#')[1];
        highlight(elemId);
    });
</script>
```

Also, no need to use `var`. Use `let` or `const`. And in the `setTimeout` there is no need to select the element by ID again. Just take the `elem`. 
FYI - the `?.` makes sure not to call the function if the element with ID doesn't exist. That is called [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)